# Insertion sort mistake

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

```
int main(){
    int i,j,temp;
    int a[]={3,2,4,7,1};
    for(i=1;i<5;i++){
        temp=a[i];
        for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--){
            if(a[j]>temp)
                a[j+1]=a[j];
            else
                break;
        }
       a[j+1]=temp;//if I replace this by a[i] I am getting wrong output.
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("\n\n%d",a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

In the inner loop I am not changing the value of variable i. Then if I replace `a[j+1]=a[i]`, I am getting wrong output. Am I missing some important concept?

Comment: Please could you format the code

Comment: Also the first item of an array has an index of zero

Comment: @EdHeal Just because the loop starts at 1 doesn't mean its using the wrong indexing ... especially in a sort algorithm. note the `j=i-1` ... starting `i` at 0 would be wrong (and UB).

Comment: "I am not changing value of variable i" -- but you are changing `a[i]` (on the first iteration when `j+1` == `i`) so of course you get the wrong result if you store that rather than its original value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program looks correct to me, but the comment shows you didn't understand the intention. The inner loop shifts elements that used to be at indices strictly between `j` (final value) and `i` one place to up, thereby destroying the old value of `a[i]`. That value was set aside in `temp`, and therefore `temp` rather than `a[i]` should be assigned to the freed up slot `a[j+1]`, which is what the program does.

Since extreme cases sometimes expose bugs, you might wander what happens when `a[i]` is already larger than anything preceding it, or it when is smaller than everything preceding it. In the former case your inner loop breaks out immediately with `j==i-1`, and `temp` is put back into `a[j+1]` which is `a[i]`, which has no effect but is correct; in the latter case your inner loop runs to completion leaving `j==-1` and you are assigning `a[0]=temp`, which is correct in this case as well.

Comment: +1 for a correct and thorough answer that pinpoints the OP's confusion, and for such a contrast from some of the garbage offered by others (including the votes to close).

Answer (score 0):

To make the code more concise and therefore better and more understandable

1. Use a temporary variable to switch the values:

   ```
       for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--){
           if(a[j]>temp){
               t = a[j+1];
               a[j+1] = a[j];
               a[j] = t;
           }
           else
               break;
       }
   ```
2. After these changes the line :  `a[j+1]=temp;//if i replace this by a[i] I am getting wrong output.` is not needed.

Comment: "After these changes" -- a perfectly good insertion sort is degraded with unnecessary swaps. "To make the code more concise and therefore better and more understandable" -- How absurd; your changes do nothing of the sort. And you *didn't answer the OP's question* ... which is why `a[j+1]=temp` works but `a[j+1]=a[i]` doesn't.